# How to prevent axios from sending null values?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, axios

I have an axios.post() request configured to update a document in my MongoDB collection by sending current state, updated by textfields.

I have my state initially setup to null:

```
this.state = {

  editedCustomer: {
    name: null,
    surname: null,
    alias: null,
    email: null,
    phoneNo: null,
    _id: null
  },

}
```

These values are updated directly from text fields, so whenever a textfield receives input it updates the state, which is then sent with axios like this:

```
axios.patch(`${APIURL}/customers/updateCustomer`, {
      'name': this.state.editedCustomer.name,
      'surname': this.state.editedCustomer.surname,
      'alias': this.state.editedCustomer.alias,
      'email': this.state.editedCustomer.email,
      'phoneNo': this.state.editedCustomer.phoneNo,
      '_id': this.state.editedCustomer._id
    })
```

However, my problem is, if I only update some fields (say I only wanna update the customer's name), the rest of these fields are being posted to my backend as null and my database being populated with the updated values, with `null` now replacing the rest of the fields.

Is there any way to only post non-null values with axios, or should the change be in my /updateCustomer route within my backend. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Axios is sending null because if you're updating only certain values, the other values that are not being supplied are null.

So what you should do is in your /updateCustomer route in your backend, you only update the values that are passed in from axios instead of updating the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

You should just map over that Object using `Object.keys` and "filter" the values that are null

```
let data = {};//<- Data to send with Axios

Object.keys(this.state.editedCustomer).map((key) => {
  if(editedCustomer[key]) {
    data[key] = editedCustomer[key]
  }
});

const dataToSend = JSON.stringify(data);
```

then you just post your `dataToSend` with Axios/fetch...